# Id field mapping is broken after ensureIndex using MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following entity with custom ID field:

```
public class User : IEntity {
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(User))) {
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<User>(map => map.AutoMap());
}
```

It works pretty good, when I add new record to collection, ID value is assigned.
However, when I'm trying to index any other field within this collection:

```
UserCollection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys<User>.Ascending(p => p.Email),IndexOptions.SetUnique(true));
```

Id mapping becames broken, ID field value is null after insert and in collection I see default '_id' field generated (insead of my 'ID').
Any ideas what's the problem? (I'm using driver 1.8.3.9, mongo win32 2.4.5, NET 4.5). Thanks.

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce this. Can you post the full definitions of IEntity interface and User class. Also post some sample data from the shell showing the behavior you described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution! UserCollection.EnsureIndex was called before the class mapping, causing the problem.